# Using pipreqs and freeze to create requirements.txt

Tags: python, exe, lib

I'm learning how to use `requirements.txt` and i don't know how solve this problem:
When i run my code in Pycharm, nothing wrong happen, just creates a txt with some packages, without errors. But, when i create a `exe` using `cx_Freeze` and run it, the `requirements.txt` is created but is empty.

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

# Some useless imports to put in requirements.txt
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import pygetwindow
import PySimpleGUI
import pyautogui
import importlib.util
import psutil
import PySimpleGUI as pys
from time import sleep

# Command that i use
os.system(r'cmd /c pipreqs')

# Just a final window to verify if run correctly
layout = [
    [pys.Text(f'Complete =)', size=(25, 0))],
]
jan = pys.Window('Test', layout=layout, finalize=True)
jan.read()
```

When i use `os.system('cmd /c pip freeze > requirements.txt')` and run, the `requirements.txt` is not created (running with exe)

> i try `pip install pipreqs` and no solved

> I also tried using `pigar`, in pycharm works but when is `exe` doesn't create a txt file

Basically, my code only works in PyCharm, and no matters what i try, don't works if is `exe`
What i can do?

Comment: @udoyhasan I want create a ```txt``` file and posteriorly install, but i can't solve problem with creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make `requirements.txt` with `pipreqs` and upload to my GitHub, always that i need to download this libs i use `pip install --no-cache-dir -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UserName/some_folder/requirements.txt` to install all packages